# How long can a manga (or other work) can go hiatus

Tags: manga-production

Sometimes a manga went hiatus for quite long time, for example HxH was on hiatus from 2014 to 2016

[image: HxH hiatus chart]
<sub>Source https://hiatus-hiatus.github.io/</sub>

If there are no health issue or any major problem, since it can't be helped if that was the case, how long can a manga or any other work go on hiatus? What if the mangaka didn't show any interest on continuing their work? Would they, the publisher, dropped it even if it was popular?

Comment: Things to consider here: as much as I know about the manga industry and japanese work culture in general, it seems like it's a pretty personal thing between the author and the important people in charge of these decisions. So they might have a huge fan among the key decisionmakers and they refuse to drop a manga despite long hiatuses. Also, it might be that it's not in the best interests of a big name regular journal to drop a successful author who may sometimes take unprecedented breaks. Where's he gonna go when/if he makes more chapters? To another publisher? Could not be a possibility.

Comment: At least longer than 5 years? [‘Black Lagoon’ manga may return after 6-year hiatus](http://lifestyle.inquirer.net/259608/black-lagoon-manga-may-return-after-6-year-hiatus/), though the author has released some in 2013 sparingly. Also, a list of [Best Hiatus manga](http://www.anime-planet.com/manga/tags/hiatus) (note the difference between 'hiatus' and 'cancelled')

Comment: @AkiTanaka why vagabond marked hiatus on that site ? i thought it's already ended in 2015...

Comment: @Gagantous [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vagabond_(manga)) (and its Japanese counterpart) hasn't mentioned the end date which is usually shown when the series ends. Also, [MangaUpdates](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=387) mentions "*37 Volumes (Hiatus)*".

Comment: well... X (CLAMP) has been on hiatus since 2003...

Comment: @paulnamida for real ?

Comment: @Gagantous for real. And it's not the only series CLAMP has had on hiatus for a long while, but it certainly is the longest... and there's no plan to resume it anytime soon... if ever

Comment: @paulnamida so are they have other  manga that still ongoing ?

Comment: Yeah, they are currently doing a sequel of sorts for Card Captor Sakura